# Does the -loop-unroll pass force LLVM to unroll loops?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have a piece of code and I want LLVM to unroll all loops in it by a certain factor. I'm using the following command:

`opt -mem2reg -simplifycfg -loops -lcssa -loop-simplify -loop-rotate -loop-unroll -unroll-count=3 -unroll-allow-partial -debug TrainingCode/trainingCode.ll -o TrainingCode/unrolledTrainingCode.bc`

Specifically, the `-loop-unroll` and `-unroll-count=3` handle the loop unrolling stuff - the rest just transforms the code so that LLVM can unroll the code.

Does this command guarantee that all loops will be unrolled by a factor of 3? Or is it more like using pragma statements with GCC, which the compiler can choose to ignore if it deems non-optimal? In other words, do the `-loop-unroll` and `-unroll-count=3` passes *force* the compiler to use an unroll factor of 3 or is it more of a "hint" the compiler can choose to ignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this command guarantee that all loops will be unrolled by a
>   factor of 3?

The short answer is no.

First of all, it depends on the loop. For example, if it is a pointer-chasing loop, that is a major inhibiting factor. A determining factor for the unroll is to be able to calculate the trip count at compile time. Thus, a major help to loop unrolling is performing the `indvars` pass.

Snooping around `LoopUnroll.cpp` and `LoopUnrollPass.cpp` can be illuminating. Among other things, there are statistics kept like `NumCompletelyUnrolled` and `NumUnrolled` that can give a rough-cut overall status. Next, there are metadata that can be taken into account as a hint (search for `GetLoopUnrollMetadata` which complements what @schaiba wrote). One more thing to follow in the pass source file is the `TripCount` and how that is used in order to determine the exact policy for unrolling the loop.

PS: My notes are based on the `LLVM` 3.7 source tree, so that's why I was not very definite in the descriptions. YMMV depending on the version you're working on, but those things are mostly there in the latest trunk (6.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, loop unrolling is [translated](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#loop-unrolling) into `#pragma`s . If the unroll count is not known at compile time, unrolling will not take place. If you choose full unrolling, that means LLVM will indeed eliminate the loop.